# Azure SAS connection is not working with Azure.Storage.Blobs

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure.Storage.Blobs, Version=12.1.0.0.
Blobclient is working fine with AccessKey ,but we wanted to use SAS connectionstring
It is throwing exception here.

`var blobClient = new BlobServiceClient(**Connectionstring**);`

`"No valid combination of account information found."` this is the exception am getting at the above line.

I am using the below SAS connection format
BlobEndpoint=xxxxxxx;QueueEndpoint=xxxxxxx;FileEndpoint=xxxxxxx;TableEndpoint=xxxxxxx;SharedAccessSignature=xxxxxxx

Answer (score 4):

For SAS connection, you should follow the steps below to generate sas-url: Nav to azure portal -> your storage account -> Shared access signature:

[image]

Then copy the "Blob Service SAS URL"(if you want to operate file share / queue, you should use the respective SAS URL).

Then in the code with library Azure.Storage.Blobs, Version=12.1.0.0.:

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp16
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //replace the sas_url with the one you copied in the above steps.
            string sas_url = "https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=2019-02-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2020-01-07T17:04:27Z&st=2020-01-07T09:04:27Z&spr=https&sig=xxx";
            Uri uri = new Uri(sas_url);
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(uri);

            var blobContainer = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("test1");

            var blobclient = blobContainer.GetBlobClient("yy1.txt");
            blobclient.Upload(@"d:\aa.txt");


            Console.WriteLine("**completed**");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @santhoshisirangi  if the answer works for you, could you please help mark it as answer as per this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)? Thanks.

Comment: @santhoshisirangi, Hello, since it's working now, could you please [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)? Just take you around 3-4 seconds. And it's very important to me. Really thanks.